# How do I configure proxies without GUI?

Tags: proxy

How do you configure proxy settings in the Ubuntu Server or Minimal (CLI) versions using the terminal?

Answer (score 120):

System-wide proxies in CLI Ubuntu/Server must be set as environment variables.

- Open the `/etc/environment` file with `vi` (or your favorite editor). This file stores the system-wide variables initialized upon boot.
- Add the following lines, modifying appropriately. You must duplicate in both upper-case and lower-case because (unfortunately) some programs only look for one or the other:

  ```
  http_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
  https_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
  ftp_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
  no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
  HTTP_PROXY="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
  HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
  FTP_PROXY="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
  NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
  ```
- `apt-get`, `aptitude`, etc. will not obey the environment variables when used normally with `sudo`. So separately configure them; create a file called `95proxies` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, and include the following:

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
  Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
  Acquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
  ```

Finally, logout and reboot to make sure the changes take effect.

---

Sources: [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/357688/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-on-linux-xfce). See 1 in particular for additional help, including a script to quickly turn on/off the proxies.

Comment: I need help on this. I've been trying this on a virtual Ubuntu Server 12.04 for a while now and it's not working. I have it working with a virtual Ubuntu 12.04 (non server). But I used the GUI to apply global settings. 
I've tried with quotes as the lower link suggests, and it didn't help. If I'm entering an IP address instead of a domain.com name does the formatting change? I've tried several combinations of things.

Comment: are you sure https_proxy="http ?

Comment: Well, this isn't a great answer in my view because the (incorrect) proxy info I gave at install time is not located in /etc/environment.

Comment: In my case, Ubuntu 12.04, it was not necessary to logout and reboot to make sure the changes take effect. I execute: sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: @BBK even when using https, you may still have to connect to the proxy via http, which basically enables the proxy server to eavesdrop on your presumably safe connection.

Comment: @Doc It's almost definitely in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

Comment: Note that you have are using an https url in the Acquire line for https. Don't you mean to use http://myproxy.server.com:8080/?

Comment: Note that I had some problems with quoting the paths. I removed the quotes and everything worked fine!

Comment: also watch out for ```/etc/profile.d.```  These settings could be in that folder as well.

Comment: This does work on archlinux ,even msys2(Windows). But not work on ubuntu, I keep getting  `Proxy request sent, awaiting response... No data received` .

Comment: do we still need to configure url in the browser to access internet through proxy ?? ( eq. inside  firefox settings > Configure proxies to access internet  )

Answer (score 10):

If you have an authenticating proxy, then the URLs will  be different. Instead of:

```
"http://myproxy.server.com:8080/"
```

You'll have:

```
"http://user_name:password@myproxy.server.com:8080/"
```

Note that these are still URLs, so passwords (and possibly usernames) will have to be [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

For example, a username of `muru` and a password of `)qv3TB3LBm7EkP}` would look like:

```
"http://muru:)qv3TB3LBm7EkP%7D@myproxy.server.com:8080/"
```

This can be done in various ways:

1. There several websites for encoding:

   - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
   - http://www.url-encode-decode.com/
   - http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm
     etc.
2. Programmatic:

   - [A `bash` script from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script)
   - [In Perl, from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510550/using-perl-how-do-i-decode-or-create-those-encodings-on-the-web)

In a pinch, you can use [`man url`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/url) to see which characters need to be encoded:

```
An escaped octet is encoded as a character triplet, 
consisting of the percent character "%" followed by 
the two hexadecimal digits representing the octet code...
```

And the octet codes are available on [`man ascii`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ascii).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>                                  Proxy Environment Variables:
> ```
>
> http_proxy:  Proxy server for HTTP Traffic
>   https_proxy: Proxy server for HTTPS traffic
>   ftp_proxy:   Proxy server for FTP traffic
>   no_proxy:    Patterns for IP addresses or domain names that shouldn’t use the proxy

The value for every proxy setting, except for no_proxy, uses the same template. 
`proxy_http=username:password@proxy-host:port`

Temporary setting proxy:
`export HTTP_PROXY=user:pass@my.proxy.server:8080`

Persistent Proxy Settings:
use `vim ~/.bash_profile` to open bash setup file, then put following lines inside it

```bsh
export http_proxy=username:password@proxyhost.com:8080
export https_proxy=username:password@proxyhost.com:8081
export no_proxy=localhost, 127.0.0.1, *.my.lan
```

use `source ~/.bash_profile` to apply the changes

Comment: Thanks, I’ve corrected it.