# Lynx "Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host."

Tags: 12.04, lynx

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu server. I'm running

> Distributor ID:
>   Ubuntu Description:
>   Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 
>   Release:  12.04

I have installed Lynx via

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

everything installed fine but when I try to connect to a website it just seems to time out.

When I run `lynx google.com` it goes to a blank screen with a blue line at the bottom. There is yellow text on the line which says

**"Making HTTP connection to google.com"**

but it just sits there.

Eventually after 5 - 6 minutes it just goes back to the normal terminal window

If I run the below on its own

```
lynx
```

I get the same blue line with the same text

**"Making HTTP connection to google.com"**

but after 30 seconds or so it briefly turns to a red line with

**"alert!: lynx unable to connect to remote host"**

written on it.

I have installed lynx locally and it works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is DNS (name resolution) correctly configured on the server? can you successfully `ping google.com` from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the above comments and answers I found the issue. My /etc/enviroments file was blank. I followed the instructions in this question

[How do I configure proxies without GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-in-ubuntu-server-or-minimal-cli-ubuntu)

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
lynx -source http://www.google.com | sh
```

Chek also `~/.lynx` maybe there is something wrong with the proxy settings.

Comment: why the `| sh` at the end?