# How to make my server A to work as proxy for traffic of server B?

Tags: proxy

I need acces to WAN from remote server(server B), and I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on pc(server B) at that WAN, so I need to set up that PC to work as tunnel for server A .

Comment: How can ServerA access ServerB? same LAN, ssh with public ip?

Comment: server B is on another ISP ip , another country country B on WAN B
server A is on WAN A in country A
both have public IP and on both I connect via putty SSH

Comment: i think you have 2 options (maybe more). One is setup a proxy on ServerB and [configure network ServerA to proxy all traffic](http://askubuntu.com/a/175177/260379). The other option is to route traffic from ServerA [through a ssh tunnel to ServerB](http://superuser.com/a/311863/612663)

Comment: I haven't fount anything that is similar to my situation, its everything about servers on same lan, and if I found something that is similar to my situation it is explained realy bad.

Comment: both of the described choices, proxy and ssh tunnel,  are possible on LAN/WAN, just change the ips from local to public. Of course proxy should be authenticated and you need to open/forward the appropiate ports on machine and router.

Comment: hm, I will reformulate my question, so I beileve you will tell me what I need.
I know how to configure proxy on server.
Question is , how can I set up my pc ubuntu 14.04 installed  to work as proxy?? So I can put that address on one or several server on another wan?

Comment: Squid seems to be the de-facto proxy on linux when searching "setup proxy server ubuntu 14.04", [tinyProxy is a nice option](http://markus.revti.com/2009/10/installing-tinyproxy-as-squid-proxy-server-alternative/)